I'm using text-generation library of Python to call a hugging-face inference API for text-generation purposes. But I keep getting this user-warning
import text_generation
def generate_job_responsibilities(job_title, work_experience_required, skillset_required):
    client = text_generation.InferenceAPIClient("OpenAssistant/oasst-sft-4-pythia-12b-epoch-3.5", token=<my huggingface token>)

I tried running the solution it shows on the terminal.
`UserWarning: Field "model_id" has conflict with protected namespace "model_".
You may be able to resolve this warning by setting
model_config['protected_namespaces'] = ()`.
  warnings.warn(


You're importing a module (import text_generation) then treating it like a class (text_generation.InferenceAPIClient) which isn't valid python, but there's not really enough information to work our what the exact issue is.

@DavidWaterworth Uh, what? The module apparently contains a class with that name.

https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/7121 suggests that text_generation uses pydantic under the hood but you have a newer version than they developed it for. You should probably raise a bug with the maintainer. In the meantime, see if downgrading pydantic to the lowest acceptable version allows your code to work.

@tripleee yeah you're correct - the huggingface-hub library has a InferenceClient class with a text_generation method (https://huggingface.co/docs/text-generation-inference/en/basic_tutorials/consuming_tgi#inference-client) which confused me.
